# How to compute Betti numbers of compact homogenous spaces?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, homogeneous-spaces, betti-numbers

Is it an easy problem computing Betti numbers of compact homogenous spaces?

I want to compute Betti numbers of well-known compact Riemannian homogenous spaces like $\mathsf{Sp}(2)/\mathsf{SU}(2)$ and $\Big(\mathsf{SU}(3)\times \mathsf{SO}(3)\Big)/\mathsf{U}^\star(2)$ where $\mathsf{U}^\star(2)$ is the image under the embedding
$(\iota; \pi): \mathsf{U}(2)\hookrightarrow \mathsf{SU}(3) \times \mathsf{SO}(3)$ given by the natural inclusion and the projection $\pi:\mathsf{U}(2)\rightarrow\mathsf{U}(2)/\Bbb S^1\cong   \mathsf{SO}(3)$.

I have seen constructing exact sequence using fiber bundles but I don't remember the exact procedure.

How to compute Betti numbers of such compact homogenous spaces?

Related post: [Cohomology group of some homogeneous spaces obtained from Lie groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4184075/272127)

Comment: It's hard but, in principle, doable. The only reference I know, though is: A.Borel, Sur la cohomologie des espaces fibrés principaux et des espaces homogènes de groupes de Lie compacts. Ann. of Math. (2) 57 (1953), 115–207.

Comment: It is not useful knowing Betti numbers of homogenous spaces? So why there is almost no work about it?

Comment: Did I say "almost no work"? Many people use Borel's procedure as a tool for specific computations. What I meant is that I do not know any general treatment besides the one by Borel.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: Sorry for my comment. By "almost no work" I meant I couldn't find any paper about it.